# Angular / Typescript, how to reuse types

Tags: angular, typescript

How to take out **types** separately and be able to reuse them. In my case, I use type duplication, which is not correct.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})

export class LinkInitComponent implements OnInit {

  public linkKind: 'phoneLink' | 'emailLink' | 'routerLink' | 'simpleLink' | 'simpleText';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.linkKind = this.initLinlType();
  }


  private initLinlType(): 'phoneLink' | 'emailLink' | 'routerLink' | 'simpleLink' | 'simpleText' {
    return 'simpleText'
  }
}
```

Comment: `type LinkKind = ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
declare type Link = 'phoneLink' | 'emailLink' | 'routerLink' | 'simpleLink' | 'simpleText';
```

useable like this:

```js
public linkKind: Link;
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQGQJYDsDW8AvPAOSoAWA9jiNvifAD6kgC2UWEdeDzJMlAK6IQMbr1IBnLK1QRauHkyky5IACogAHohIBuAFAGAbrCRoQwbgC543IqQrUF9IA) is an example.

Comment: The thing is I should do this outside the class. This was my mistake. Thank you.